# Как можно через терминал установить grub в Linux mint'е

Tags: linux, консоль, ос, grub

Вопрос такой: после установки Linux mint при загрузки системы показывается сам логотип системы! да и сама система полностью загружается и функционирует только интерфейс grub отсутствует.

Answer (score 2):

нашёл решение!! *решил оставить пост МОЖЕТ комунибуть пригодится!!! решение проблемы оказывается куда прошё чем казалось.
..................................................................
Если ваш компьютер использует BIOS для загрузки, нажмите и удерживайте Shift клавишу во время загрузки GRUB, чтобы открыть меню загрузки. Если ваш компьютер использует UEFI для загрузки, нажмите Esc несколько раз во время загрузки GRUB, чтобы открыть меню загрузки.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант - установить Grub Customizer и спокойно редактировать меню.
[https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer](https://launchpad.net/%7Edanielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer)
Установка из PPA для Linux Mint 19 и ниже. Для Linux Mint 20 в терминале sudo apt install grub-customizer из официальных реп.

Или правите в терминале sudo xed /etc/default/grub
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="menu" -- визуализация меню
GRUB_TIMEOUT="10" -- время в сек

После сохранения изменений в терминале sudo update-grub